# What's the difference between 3G and Wifi in iOS5?

Tags: ios5, twitter, reachability

Got some problem in here, in my application, I'm using Twitter API in showing the timeline of different users. The weird thing is, it's doing fine if my connection is WIFI, but when I switch to 3G, my Application crashes... Can somebody explain me what's the reason behind this weird experience? Great thanks ...

The crash log is

```
2012-08-29 16:17:23.847 PFAv1[4044:707] array of tweets count 2 
2012-08-29 16:17:23.850 PFAv1[4044:707] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21b7e0 
2012-08-29 16:17:23.854 PFAv1[4044:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21b7e0'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not everybody has got psychic ability to answer this question without crash logs.

Comment: The crash log is 2012-08-29 16:17:23.847 PFAv1[4044:707] array of tweets count 2
2012-08-29 16:17:23.850 PFAv1[4044:707] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21b7e0
2012-08-29 16:17:23.854 PFAv1[4044:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21b7e0'

Comment: The weird thing really is, when my connection is WIFI, I get 10 tweets which is indicated on my count parameter. But when I'm using 3G, I only get 2 tweets, When I say tweets, the responsedata count from twitter api is only 2 considering my request parameter count is 10. Again, my code works fine in WIFI but crashes when I'm in 3G ... Help Please. Thanks

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are trying to access NSArray but actually you are accessing NSDictionary. Post the method where this error appears.